# What is requests.exceptions.ConnectionError in python requests?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, socket-timeout-exception, connectionexception

What does the following error mean?

```
socket.timeout: The read operation timed out 
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='', port=443): Read
timed out. 
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='', port=443): Read timed out.
```

**Here is my code:**

```
def get(url):
    while True:
        try:
            response = session.get(url, timeout=.5).text
            break
        except requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout:
            new_session()
    return response

r = get(url)
```

Where `session` is a session that I've made and `new_session()` closes that session and set session to a new session via `requests.session()`